# R terminal buffer

Tags: r, terminal, rstudio

SAMPLE FROM RSTUDIO

Start a command with results displayed in a terminal buffer

```
termId <- rstudioapi::terminalExecute("ping rstudio.com")
```

If viewing the result in the terminal buffer is sufficient,
 then no need to do anything else. The command will continue
 running and displaying its results without blocking the R session.

To obtain the results programmatically, wait for it to finish.

```
while (is.null(rstudioapi::terminalExitCode(termId))) {
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}

result <- rstudioapi::terminalBuffer(termId)
```

Delete the buffer and close the session in the IDE

```
rstudioapi::terminalKill(termId)
```

My goal is to 'PING' multiple website for examples:

```
c = c("google.com","bing.com","rstudio.com")
```

I want to put this in the sleep loop so the code that comes after ping does not get run yet until the ping process finishes. I want to print that every ping process is complete once it is and then a final message when all the pings are done and then last to clear and close all terminal windows.

Comment: I'm a little confused: most of the "question" looks like instructions from homework or a tutorial, and then you ask about how to `ping` multiple websites. What function are you using to even try to ping one host? (BTW: it's not good practice to name a variable `c`; even though R will typically do the right thing, (1) if you forget to name it in follow-on scripts, errors are *really* confusing; (2) it's difficult for those more familiar with R to look at your code and instantly know what you're doing. (This is compounded by `c = c(...)`.)

Comment: This I copy from tutorial but I try to modify this with no success. I want to execute multiple "pings" but while doing that not run any commands that come after and also print when each one finish.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the RStudio API instead of `system2` or perhaps the `processx::` package? (I can't really help, I don't use RStudio regularly, and most of the `rstudioapi::` functions do not work outside of their IDE.)

Comment: Perhaps if you just want to do a check-ping (*"one ping only"*), you should look into options to `ping` that restrict the number of packets sent and the timeout to call pass/fail. These arguments depend on your OS, so having that would help.

Comment: if i run lots of process then I have 80+ terminal windows open. how I can close them all with one command? i currently close all the boxes and it takes much time.

Comment: The need for an R `ping` function is not new to SO. I've extended it with my answer, but it's just another function.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bite. Here's a quick function and use of it:

```r
ping <- function(hosts, count = 1, timeout = 1, all. = FALSE) {
  GOOD <- TRUE
  if (R.version$os == "mingw32") {
    countopt <- "-n"
    timeoutopt <- "-w"
    timeout <- timeout * 1000 # milliseconds
  } else {
    countopt <- "-c"
    timeoutopt <- "-w"
  }
  success <- fail <- character(0)
  for (host in hosts) {
    out <- suppressWarnings(
      system2("ping", c(countopt, count, timeoutopt, as.character(timeout), shQuote(host)),
              stdout = FALSE, stderr = FALSE)
    )
    if (out == 0) {
      success <- c(success, host)
    } else {
      fail <- c(fail, host)
      GOOD <- FALSE
      if (!all.) break
    }
  }
  attr(GOOD, "ping_success") <- success
  attr(GOOD, "ping_fail") <- fail
  GOOD
}
```

The default behavior is to ping each in turn, and return `TRUE` only if all succeeded. This stops and returns on the first fail:

```r
ping(c("google.com", "bing.com", "rstudio.com"))
# [1] TRUE
# attr(,"ping_success")
# [1] "google.com"  "bing.com"    "rstudio.com"
# attr(,"ping_fail")
# character(0)
```

By default, it stops after the first fail and includes its progress (in the attributes):

```r
ping(c("google.com", "quux.not", "rstudio.com"))
# [1] FALSE
# attr(,"ping_success")
# [1] "google.com"
# attr(,"ping_fail")
# [1] "quux.not"
```

If you need to know which are good regardless of the fails, then

```r
ping(c("google.com", "quux.not", "rstudio.com"), all. = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE
# attr(,"ping_success")
# [1] "google.com"  "rstudio.com"
# attr(,"ping_fail")
# [1] "quux.not"
```

Because it reports its happiness/sadness as *attributes*, you should always be able to rely on a singular `logical` value and, if needed, dive deeper into what worked or didn't work.